# Dynamic Dropdown List PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and trying to make dynamic list box using SQL

```
<label> Select Sport</label>
<select name = "Sport">
    <option value = "">Select Sport</option>

    <?php
    $all = "SELECT * FROM EventTable";
    $result = $pdo->query($all);
    foreach($result as $Sport){
    ?>
       <option value ="<?php echo $Sport['Sport']; ?>"></option>
    <?php
    }
   ?>
</select>
```

But its printing BLANK space

[image]

Comment: Try `<option value ="<?php echo $Sport['Sport']; ?>"><?php echo $Sport['Sport']; ?></option>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select name="">
foreach($result as $Sport){
?>
    <option value ="<?php echo $Sport['Sport']; ?>"><?php echo $Sport['Sport']; ?></option>    // The value between <option> value </option> is the value which is to be shown in the dropdown, without this it is showing blank 
<?php
}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't use SELECT *, but since you're learning, I digress. Also, I personally have a hard time reading a lot of opening and closing php tags scattered throughout plus they often give weird results than what you're expecting, so this is how I'd write it.

```
<?php

 $all = "SELECT * FROM EventTable";
 $result = $pdo->query($all);
 foreach($result as $sport)
 {
      echo "<option value =" . $sport['Sport'] . ">" . $sport['Sport'] . "</option>";
 }

?>
```

The blank spaces indicates that you are actually hitting the loop and iterating, but the values for that array item are null. Are you sure the field name isn't 'sport' instead of 'Sport'?